# Наложение картинок и их загрузка на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование

Доброго времени суток!

Задача такова: на сайт загружается картинка. Выбирается один из нескольких слоев для наложения поверх нее (тоже картинка) И возможность загрузить полученное изображение. [(Пример)](http://www.gastreet.com/avatar/)
Код из примера не получается использовать, т.к. основная часть ресурсов находится на backend.

Вопрос в следующем: Как можно реализовать данный функционал? Что использовать? Может какие библиотеки кто подскажет. Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно Ajax'ом подгружать картинку на сервер откуда будешь ее тянуть на задний фон под маски, и повесить trigger или же подставлять url в кнопочку download; советую хотя бы ui подключить или на keydown event, чтобы была возможность передвигать картинку в разные стороны

Comment: Спасибо) С загрузкой на страничку я уже почти разобрался. а каким образом загружать полученную картинку, состоящую уже из 2-х.

Comment: На ссылку повесь download, а href="url картинки на сервере" примерно так http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/download

Comment: Очень помогаете!!!) ещё несколько вопросов если не сложно: как "Натянуть" картинку на задний фон под маски. И второе: что такое и как подключается это ui, что бы была возможность двигать картинку

Comment: вообще по разному можно сделать, можно обернуть в div
ex:
<div style="background: url(маски); z-index:9">
      <img style="z-index:-9" src="url(переменная ajax, которая отвечает за загрузку картинки)"/>
</div>
как вариант, динамически менять маску на которую тебе нужно.
ui jquery: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/, чтобы можно было курсором двигать картинку, или же keydown event: https://api.jquery.com/keydown/ или на нативной эта же функция, чтобы по клику на клавиши менять положения картинки.

Comment: А разве если я добавлю картинку на сервер, затем на неё "надену" мою картинку, и потом сделаю download с помощью ссылки, которой укажу свой href - то скачается же именно та картинка которую я загрузил без того что я повесил сверху. Разе нет?)